# how to add passport js (local-strategy) in all routes

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I added the passport authenticated to my login route but I do not know how to add it to the other routes. now (req.isAuthenticated) is true in the login route but It's false in all of the other routes!!! How can I add it to all routes so that when the user is logged in, 'req.authenticated' becomes true on them?

> login.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");
const passport = require("passport");

const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { getAdmins } = require("../queries/queries");

//middlewares
router.use(flash());
router.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
router.use(methodOverride('_method'));

//passport
const initializePassport = require("../passport-config");
initializePassport(
  passport,
  async (name) => {
    let users = await getAdmins();
    return users.find((user) => user.name == name)},
  async (id) => {
    let users = await getAdmins();
    return users.find((user) => user.id == id)}
);

//get metod
router.get("/", checkAuthentication, (req, res) => {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname, "../public/login.ejs"), {isLogin : req.isAuthenticated});
});

//post method
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/messages",
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);

router.delete('/logout', (req, res)=>{
  req.logOut();
  res.redirect('/');
})

//check req authenticated
function checkAuthentication(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('login:yes')
      return next();
    }
    console.log('login:no');
    return next();
}

module.exports = router;
```

> passport-config.js:

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

function initialize(passport, getUserByName, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (name, password, done) => {
    const user = await getUserByName(name);
    if (user == null) return done(null, false, { message: "sorry! user name is not exist" });
    if(password == user.password){
        return done(null, user);
    } else done(null, false, {message : "incorrect password"});
  };
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(authenticateUser));
  passport.serializeUser((user, done)=> done(null, user.id));
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=> done(null, getUserById(id)));
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I transferred this code from login.js to server.js:

```
//midlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
```